# bash script works on online compiler but not within Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a bash script that
- takes in two inputs (and only two)
- then prints out all the even numbers between the two numbers
- prints out orange beside any number divisible also by 7
- prints out banana beside any number divisible also by 11
- prints out pear beside any number divisible also by 13
finally prints out a statement "what is with the fruit obsession?"

it works fine within this compiler (http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php)
but in Linux it error messages saying that $Input2 is not a recognised identifier and that there is an unexpected end of file after the last line

```
    #!/bin/bash
     read -p "Type in Two integer inputs you want evaluated, followed by [ENTER]:" Input1 Input2
      if [ -z $Input1 ]; then
        echo "Please enter a valid first integer"
        read -r Input1 Input2
    exit 1
    fi
    if [ -z $Input2 ]; 
  then
        echo "Please enter a valid second integer"
        read Input2
    fi
    if [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "Too many numbers have been inputted"
    fi
  echo "You entered: $Input1,$Input2"
  echo "Here are all the even numbers between your two values:" 
  echo ""
  # if Input 1 is larger than Input 2
  while [ $((Input2)) -lt $Input1 ]; do
    if [ $((Input1 % 2)) -gt 0 ];then
  echo -en "$((Input1 = $Input1 - 1)) "
  else
  echo -en "$((Input1 = $Input1 - 2)) "
  fi
    if [ $((Input1 % 7)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "orange "
    fi
    if [ $((Input1 % 11)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "banana "
    fi
    if [ $((Input1 % 13)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "pear "
    fi
    echo
  done;

    while [ $((Input1)) -lt $Input2 ]; do
    if [ $((Input2 % 2)) -gt 0 ];then
    echo -en "$((Input2 = $Input2 - 1)) "
  else
    echo -en "$((Input2 = $Input2 - 2)) "
  fi

    if [ $((Input2 % 7)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "orange "
    fi
    if [ $((Input2 % 11)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "banana "
    fi
    if [ $((Input2 % 13)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -en "pear "
    fi
    echo
  done;

  echo "what is with the fruit obsession?"
  exit 0
```

Comment: Don't indent the shebang if you want to be sure it runs in Bash.

Comment: Your script works fine for me on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).  Do you possibly edit the script using a windows text editor, then copy to Linux?  If so your line terminators could be messed up.  Use `dos2unix` to fix.

Comment: I'm also forced to say: _"what is with the fruit obsession?"_

Comment: I used a windows editor and then ran it on Linux

Comment: When you ran it where there any error messages at all

Comment: @user3498994 works fine for me with no errors, because I pasted from this page directly to a Linux text editor, so the line terminators were set up correctly from that editor.

Comment: There are a bunch of quoting errors in here. `[ -z "$Input1" ]`, not `[ -z $Input1 ]`; the latter _does_ return true when Input1 is empty, but not because it's evaluating it with the `-z` operator -- rather, it evaluates to `[ -z ]`, which tests whether the string `-z` is non-null. When you get an `Input1` with more than one word in it, though, then the non-quoted version gets very, very buggy.

Comment: Also, `echo -e` isn't specified by POSIX; neither is `-n`, for that matter. Your much, much better option is to use `printf`.

Comment: Also, if you're depending on bash, you can use `if (( Input1 % 13 == 0 ))` and `(( $# > 2 ))`, both of which are considerably easier to read than messing around with `-eq`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @CharlesDuffy i've made those changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dos2unix` to convert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) windows-style line terminators `\r\n` to *nix-style `\n`:

```
dos2unix fruit.sh
```

Note I used the inverse `unix2dos` on the script and then when I run it I get the same errors:

```
$ ./fruit.sh
Type in Two integer inputs you want evaluated, followed by [ENTER]:2 8
You entered: 2,8
Here are all the even numbers between your two values:

6 
4 
2 
what is with the fruit obsession?
$ unix2dos fruit.sh 
unix2dos: converting file fruit.sh to DOS format ...
$ ./fruit.sh
Type in Two integer inputs you want evaluated, followed by [ENTER]:1 2
': not a valid identifier `Input2
./fruit.sh: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'/fruit.sh: line 36: `  done;
$
```

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working.  [Upvotes for accepted answers will be graciously accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) :)

Comment: Please accept my upvote.  (Esp. for reverse engineering the bug.)

Answer (score 0):

This code is not only shorter and easier to read, but it should also run MUCH faster. It's output is near identical to the original script, the exception being how it handles input.

As I tested this on a Linux machine, I don't know how it runs under cygwin.

```
#!/bin/bash

repeat=yes
while [ $repeat = "yes" ]; do
    read -p "Type in Two integer inputs you want evaluated, followed by [ENTER]: " Input1 Input2 Input3
    repeat=no
    [ -z $Input2 ] && { echo "Incorect: Not Enough Inputs"; repeat=yes ;}
    [ ! -z $Input3 ] && { echo "Incorect: Too many inputs"; repeat=yes;}
done

echo -e "You entered: $Input1,$Input2\nHere are all the even numbers between your two values:"

if [ $Input1 -lt $Input2 ]; then
    larg=$Input1 ; small=$Input2
else
    larg=$Input2 ; small=$Input1
fi

while [ $larg -lt $small ]; do
    ((small % 2)) && { echo ; echo -en "$((small = $small - 1)) " ;}
    ((small % 7)) || echo -en "orange "
    ((small % 11)) || echo -en "banana "
    ((small % 13)) || echo -en "pear "
    small=$(($small - 1))
done
echo
```

Comment: Thank you @KeithReynolds I'll keep ur code as an example for later. But I'll retain  my own code because its more understandable to me